# Is there a MarkLogic JavaScript API to Create Users and Add Roles?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

The XQuery Security Admin API info is posted here.

http://docs.marklogic.com/sec:create-user

I may be missing something but I don't see the equivalent JavaScript Security Admin APIs.

Is this the case? If so can we expect this in the next MarkLogic release?

Answer (score 5):

The sec:* functions are implemented in the XQuery library module

/MarkLogic/security.xqy

as noted in

http://docs.marklogic.com/sec

Like any XQuery library module, the security module can be imported in server-side JavaScript, and the functions can be called:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/functions#id_67468

Hoping that helps,